# Create new array from found values in array (JSON+Groovy)

Tags: json, groovy

I have an array:

```
R = [ [ Period:[ Price:[x:1, Date:2011, NewPrice:1.000],
                 PriceX:[PriceY:2, Date:2012, NewPrice:1.000] ] ] ]
```

for example. I need to create new array with values of elements Date:

```
 dates = [2011, 2012]
```

(Date can exist anywhere from this array). I can create by path in cycle:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def R = newJsonSlurper().parseText(String.valueOf(messageExchange.getResponseContent()));

M = R.Period
size = M.size()
def dates = []

for ( i in 0.. (size-1))
{
    def y = M[i].Date
    dates.add(y)
}
```

But maybe I can create array by methods findAll() or another?

response:

```
{
  "F":{
    "Stan":{
      "Form":{
        "Fin":{
          "Period":[
            {
              "PeriodEnd":"2013-12-31",
              "PeriodF":{
                "PeriodF":[
                  {
                    "PeriodEndDate":"2013-10-10",
                    "PeriodFiling":{
                      "C":{
                        "X":"B",
                        "RepTo":"1.0",
                        "Reported":"B"
                      },
                      "Final":"1",
                      "Or":"2014-01:47:00",
                      "Units":{
                        "X":"M",
                        "Reported":"M"
                      }
                    },
                    "Period":"A",
                    "SDate":"2013-12-31",
                    "Stat":{
                      "Stat":[
                        {
                          "Fi":{
                            "FV":[
                              {
                                "CO":"R",
                                "VALUE":"1"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "PeriodEnd":"2013-12-31",
                          "Period":"An",
                          "De":"2013-12-31",
                          "S":{
                            "Complete":"1",
                            "C":{
                              "X":"B",
                              "CRte":"1",
                              "X":"B"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "PeriodEnd":"2011-12-31",
              "Period":{
                "Period":[
                  {
                    "PeriodEndDate":"2012-10-10",
                    "Period":{
                      "Cur":{
                        "X":"BL",
                        "Rep":"1.00",
                        "R":"BL"
                      },
                      "Final":"1",
                      "Original":"2014-01:47",
                      "Units":{
                        "X":"M",
                        "R":"M"
                      }
                    },
                    "Period":"A",
                    "StatDate":"2013-12-31",
                    "Stat":{
                      "Stat":[
                        {
                          "Fin":{
                            "FV":[
                              {
                                "C":"R",
                                "V":"1.000000"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "PeriodEnd":"2013-12-31",
                          "Period":"A",
                          "D":"2013-12-31",
                          "Statement":{
                            "Complete":"1",
                            "Currencies":{
                              "X":"B",
                              "C":"1",
                              "X":"B"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual JSON string returned by `messageExchange.getResponseContent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
def arr = [ [ Period:[ Price :[x:1, Date:2011, NewPrice:1.000],
                       PriceX:[PriceY:2, Date:2012, NewPrice:1.000] ] ] ]
```

You can do:

```
def dates = arr.Period.collectMany { it.collect { k, v -> v.Date } }
assert dates == [ 2011, 2012 ]
```

Or

```
def dates = arr.Period*.values().Date.flatten()
```

### Edit after JSON was posted:

So lets say you want `PeriodEnd`, you can do:

```
new JsonSlurper().parseText( response )
                 .F
                 .Stan
                 .Formation
                 .Fin
                 .Period
                 .PeriodEnd
```

Or if you wanted all values of `StatDate` then you could do:

```
new JsonSlurper().parseText( response )
                 .F
                 .Stan
                 .Formation
                 .Fin
                 .Period
                 .PeriodFilings
                 .PeriodFiling
                 .StatDate.flatten()
```

#### Edit #2

Or you could implement a search:

```
List findKeys( map, key ) {
    map.findResults { k, v ->
        if( k == key ) v
        else if( v instanceof Map ) findKeys( v, key )
        else if( v instanceof Collection ) v.collectMany { findKeys( it, key ) }
        else null
    }.flatten()
}

assert findKeys( data, 'PeriodEndDate' ) == ['2013-10-10', '2012-10-10']
```

Comment: I get error: No such property: Date for class:java.lang.String. It is for first answer. For second I get exception: Exception evaluating property Date. Maybe values from response have another type?

Comment: @takeshi85 What is your actual input data?  The code above works, but I assume you have a different value for `R` than you have put in the question

Comment: I have big JSON array from web service response. I know, that it contains Date element with format Date:12-13-2014. I should take value of that element and create new array

Comment: @takeshi85 Can you post a small valid example of the Json in your question?

Comment: Can I send response to your email? Thank you.

Comment: No, because that doesn't help people in the future finding this question :-(  Can you not anonymise the data and just post the first two entries of the json to the question?

Comment: I added response code. Need to create array with PeriodEnd values

Comment: @takeshi85 and what values do you want to extract?  `PeriodEnd`?

Comment: Do you mean that I should write all path to this element?

Comment: For example: I have one big response in array R. I know, that it includes element PeriodEndDate that repeats in this array and have different values. Can I use some method (just a method) for creating another array with values of this element?

Comment: @takeshi85 Added a search method

Comment: I think, I should work with XML like here http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+with+Groovy+and+XPath